# Bracelet combinations without repetitions as array in js

Tags: javascript, arrays, combinatorics

I'm trying to make a Javascript function which will return bracelets combinations from given array, but I'm not sure how to approach the problem – it seems so hard...

Basically, I want function which will receive some multidimensional array [[1,1], [2,2], [3,3], [4,4]] and return all the non-repeating permutations with some exceptions:

- No 'reverse' duplicates e.g. can't have both: [1, 2, 3] or [3, 2, 1]
- No 'circular' duplicates e.g. none: [1, 1, 2] or [1, 2, 1] or [2, 1, 1]
- No repeating e.g. [1,1,1]

everything in best traditions of bracelets combinations.

I found some JS function which have some prototype of that:

```
function bracelets(n, k) {
    var a = [],
        i = -1;
    while (++i < n) a[i] = 0;
    return genb(1, 1, 1, -1, 0, false);

    function genb(t, p, r, u, v, rs) {
        var result = [];
        if (t - 1 > (n - r) / 2 + r) {
            if (a[t - 1] > a[n - t + 2 + r]) rs = false;
            else if (a[t - 1] < a[n - t + 2 + r]) rs = true;
        }
        if (t > n) {
            if (!rs && n % p === 0) result.push(a.slice(1));
        } else {
            a[t] = a[t - p];
            v = a[t] === a[1] ? v + 1 : 0;

            if (u === -1 && a[t - 1] !== a[1]) u = r = t - 2;
            if (u === -1 || t !== n || a[n] !== a[1]) {
                if (u === v) {
                    var rev = checkrev(t, u);
                    if (rev !== -1) result = result.concat(genb(t + 1, p, rev ? t : r, u, v, rev ? false : rs));
                } else result = result.concat(genb(t + 1, p, r, u, v, rs));
            }
            for (var j = a[t - p] + 1; j < k; j++) {
                a[t] = j;
                result = result.concat(genb(t + 1, t , r, u, 0, rs));
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    function checkrev(t, i) {
        while (++i < (t + 1) / 2 + 1) {
            if (a[i] < a[t - i + 1]) return 0;
            if (a[i] > a[t - i + 1]) return -1;
        }
        return 1;
    }
}
```

yet it's extraordinary difficult to understand and there is no annotations to it. Additionally, neither I can say that it work with arrays the way I need, nor it gives a unique sets.

I would rather say that I do not entirely understand how the mathematical idea of the necklace/bracelet combinations could be applied to programming, thus my question is how would you make the bracelet combinations using applied programming. In addition, since I know JS fair enough to understand such a complex algorithms it would be really helpful to give me some simplified example in JS or explain the code above if it's easer.

Also, can this function be represented as iterative instead of recursive?

Reference (sorry can't give more that one link in appropriate format):

[Necklace > Bracelets combinations (quick and easy)](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Necklace_(combinatorics))

(More mathematical formulas: theory.cs.uvic.ca/inf/neck/NecklaceInfo.html)

(Full explanation: teaching.csse.uwa.edu.au/units/CITS7209/polya.pdf)

Comment: please add some examples of input and output.

Comment: Someone else's code that you can't get a handle on is a tough way to start.  Break the challenge down into smaller goals and work on it yourself from scratch.  Then come on back and ask a more specific question when you get stuck.  Someone will be happy to help! :)

Comment: Start writing it yourself and if you encounter an issue, then ask that question here. You haven't provided any code that you've tried so far to accomplish your task.

Comment: My code example for this question about De Bruijn sequences contains parts of what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35370539/longest-binary-sequence-with-no-equal-n-length-subsequences/35389332#35389332